# There was an error attaching the debugger to the IIS worker process

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure. I am trying to start my application in VS2012 (debugging). I am getting the error below:

There was an error attaching the debugger to the IIS worker process for URL 'http://learning.cloudapp.net:82' for role instance 'deployment18(13)......'. Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

My application is working fine when I hosted it in IIS. It worked fine when I set the website project as the start up project. But when I set the azure project as start up project and start debugging I am getting the error. I have tried almost everything I could find on the internet. Can anyone please help?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

One time I got this by loading an older Azure solution on a newer machine, another time after I upgraded to Azure SDK 2.0.

I was using IIS Express instead of regular IIS.

Each time the only thing that fixed was:

1. Install Azure SDK 2 via Web Platform Installer
2. Install Azure Powershell tools via Web Platform Installer
3. Create a new Azure Project -- do not use your old azure cloud project. Do not try to get it to work-- start fresh.
4. Foreach web/worker role that you use to have in your previous azure projects, create new web/worker roles for those as well. Do not try to get the old ones to work-- start fresh. Copy the content/files from your old ones into the new projects.

So basically, install the latest tools and then create new assemblies/packages/projects to replace the old ones.